# SELinux File Context, restorecon doesn't change 'user' Context

Tags: rhel, selinux

Using `matchpathcon` against a file (e.g. /usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache) I get:

```
/usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache  system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0
```

However:

```
# ls -alZ /usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:lib_t:s0
```

So it would appear that the file does NOT have the proper context (mismatched user portion). However, when running `restorecon -v` the file is not changed.

I can do this:

```
# chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
# ls -alZ /usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
# restorecon -v /usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 -> unconfined_t:object_r:lib_t:s0
```

So `restorecon` seems to only update the SELinux `type` of a file but not the `user` context. Is this a bug or is there an explanation for this behavior? I am thinking it may be a bug because the documentation (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html) shows a restorecon on a file with mismatched `user` context and it is changed from `unconfined_u->system_u` as expected.

OS: RedHat 7.3
SELinux: 3.13.1-102.el7_3.16

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After opening a support case I see that I was mislead by the Red Hat documentation and should have read the man page more closely:

```
# man restorecon
...
If  a  file  object  does not have a context, restorecon will write the
default context to the file object's extended  attributes.  **If  a  file
object  has  a context, restorecon will only modify the type portion of
the security context.  The -F option will force a  replacement  of  the
entire context.**
...
```

Comment: ...and I thought I hated SELinux _before_ I had this problem. I wasted so much time trying to figure this out. Thanks @LJKims!

Comment: I was banging my head against wall until I find this comment lol. Online documentation still doesn't mention this after so many years. Thanks!