# What are the reasons for the default behavior of restorecon in SELinux?

Tags: selinux

At one point when learning the administration of SELinux, the `restorecon(8)` program gave me a good headache. No matter how I tried to change the permanent file contexts with `semanage-fcontext(8)` and subsequently restore them, the user and range contexts would not change. I later found in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379029), that in order to do that, the `-F` flag must be used.

That got me asking a question - conceptually, if SELinux causes a program to break, it is then because of improperly configured rules, never because of SELinux enforcing those rules. So then (and this is my assumption) no one should have a reason to deviate from the permanent context for other purposes than troubleshooting the configuration (e.g. by using `chcon(8)`).

- Why does the default behavior of `restorecon` not restore the context exactly as it's configured and instead only restores the type?
- Are there any dangers to always using the `-F` flag?
- Shouldn't the solution to `restorecon -F` breaking some functionality be setting the *correct* permanent context, instead of partially restoring it?